# Questions shouldn't have two tags that are identical

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8064/how-is-reddits-link-karma-calculated) has three tags, two of which are *formula*.

This doesn't look right.  Shouldn't the site either forbid such things or prompt for them to be corrected?

Comment: That particular question isn't listed on the tag page for formula either.

Comment: Good catch. If you search for "formula" in the tags list, you will also notice that there are two tags with the same name.

Comment: Huh. I just tried to edit it to remove the extra tag and it didn't take. Looks like we need a Dev for this one.

Comment: I deleted both [formula] tags, saved it, and both were gone.  Then when I added back a single [formula], they both came back. ):

Comment: FWIW, "domain" looks like it might have the same weird duplication. Could this be related to migration of questions?

Comment: Yes migration questions seem to be adding duplicate tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate tags were getting inserted into our `Tags` table; a unique key has now been added (yes, this should have been done a long time ago :) .